# Do questions with "which" need auxiliary verbs to make a question?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support, wh-questions

Which is correct:

> Which websites do report unbiased news about Iran?

or

> Which websites report unbiased news about Iran?

Comment: You don't need support _do_. Interrogative determiner "which" marks the clause as interrogative.

Comment: @BillJ is it "report" or "reports" in the second ?

Comment: The subject is the plural NP "which website**s**", so the verb must be the plural "report".

Comment: @BillJ The issue is more that we don't use Subject-Auxiliary inversion when the interrogative phrase (here *which websites*) is the subject of the sentence, isn't it? You would need *do* if the question was *which website do people like in Iran?*, for example - even though *which* already marks the clause as interrogative! :)

Comment: I'm aware of that. My comment concerned the OP's specific example, nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Which websites (do) report unbiased news about Iran?
> 2. Which websites (do) people read in Iran?

Here's a test to decide if you need an auxiliary verb to make a particular question.

Write out a full answer to your question using "XYZ" to represent the missing information:

1. **XYZ** websites report unbiased news about Iran.
2. People read **XYZ** websites in Iran.

If the phrase **XYZ** is the first phrase in the answer, then you don't need to swap the Subject and the auxiliary verb in the question. So if there is no auxiliary, you don't need to insert the verb *DO*.

If the phrase **XYZ** isn't the first phrase in the answer, as with example (2), then you do need to swap the Subject and the auxiliary. If there is no auxiliary in the answer, you will need to insert the auxiliary verb *DO*.

The normal question forms for examples (1) and (2) are therefore:

> 1. Which websites report unbiased news about Iran?
> 2. Which websites do people read in Iran?

It does not matter if the question word is *which* or *who* or *whose*.

---

<sup>**Grammar Note**</sup>

<sup>The reason this test works is that we don't use Subject-auxiliary inversion (we don't swap the Subject and the auxiliary), if the *wh*- question word is the Subject of the sentence, or part of the Subject of the sentence. Because Subjects come first in normal declarative sentences, the phrase **XYZ**, will always come at the beginning of the answer if it is the Subject (or part of the Subject).</sup>